# What kind of specialized keyboard is this?

Tags: keyboard

Check out that special black keyboard behind the guy's back. WHAT IS THAT?

[link to video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs-55-design-premium-feature-tour-/new-export-options-for-epub-in-indesign-cs55/).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's some heavy usage ergonic keyboard, but who makes it or where it is from I would have no idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its a [kinesis advantage](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/advantage.htm) keyboard - by the looks of it

[image: enter link description here]

I thought it was a [maltron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltron) at first glance which is another bowl style keyboard

Comment: woah...that was very quick. +1 for you.

Comment: If you want information on keyboards [geekhack](http://geekhack.org/) is a pretty good resource. The bowl style is the *second* most unusual style i've seen so it was easy to remember - the oddest being the [datahand](http://www.datahand.com). It just so happens i was researching keyboards till recently, so i remembered this enough to be able to look it up ;p